# Sum in where/having in SQL

Tags: sql-server, sum, where-clause

In have this query:

```
select * from (
select PLAY_ID, REAL+RELEASED+PLAYABLE as bets from admin_all.ACCOUNT_TRAN_ALL
where TRAN_TYPE='GAME_SET' and LOYALTY=0 and DATETIME>'2019-10-01' ) t
order by bets desc
```

I am trying to filter the result having `bets>0`

I tried `having bets>0`

```
on t.bets>0
```

with no luck
...any idea?

Comment: You don't have a sum. Without an aggregate and a group by clause, you can't use a having clause. Did you intend to sum the value you calculate as bets?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just put the condition in the `WHERE` clause; you cannot use column aliases in this clause (because it is evaluated *before* the `SELECT` clause), so you need to repeat the expression. You may, however, use the column alias in the `ORDER BY` clause (which is evaluated *after* the `SELECT` clause).

```
SELECT
    PLAY_ID, 
    REAL + RELEASED + PLAYABLE as bets 
FROM admin_all.ACCOUNT_TRAN_ALL
WHERE 
    TRAN_TYPE = 'GAME_SET' 
    AND LOYALTY = 0
    AND DATETIME > '2019-10-01'
    AND REAL + RELEASED + PLAYABLE > 0
ORDER BY bets DESC
```